# create a date object in javascript using format yyyyMMdd

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime

i have date in format yyyyMMdd, i.e. 20160110, but unable to convert using this method new Date("20160110") as it gives invalid date error

Comment: Thats not a valid value for the constructor. `d = new Date(str.substr(0, 4), str.substr(4, 2) - 1, str.substr(6, 2))`

Comment: Careful, the month starts at index 0 so you should substract 1

Answer (score 3):

That is not a valid date format to be used with *Date()*. Instead use The [ISO 8601 syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (YYYY-MM-DD). If you have a *date* variable in `yyyymmdd` format, then you could do:

```
new Date(date.replace(/(....)(..)(..)/,"$1-$2-$3"))
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Syntax):

> ### Syntax
>
> Direct call:
>
> ```
> Date.parse(dateString)
> ```
>
> Implicit call:
>
> ```
> new Date(dateString)
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> **dateString**
> A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex :

```
var date = "20160226".match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/).map(x => +x); // ES6 to parse as integer
date[2] -= 1; // cause month starts at index 0
date = new Date(date[1], date[2], date[3])

console.log(date);
```